# Alternative to writing Multiple triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, integration

Should I build triggers for Custom_Object_A lookup objects (Custom_Object_A1, Custom_Object_A2 etc.) and then use those triggers to call an API whenever a required field value changes on these objects so that API is kept informed of any changes to the field value in Salesforce?

Writing triggers means writing service and controller classes and more the class access permissions. If there is any other efficient way, pls suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least a few alternatives to writing triggers. You could use an [Outbound Message](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_outbound_message.htm&release=234&type=5), the [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) mechanism, or even just a plain old [Replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm) calls to capture changes every few minutes. None of the above implementations require even a single line of code in Salesforce, just configure what you want it to do, and it's done.